# Android API Level Inconsistencies

Tags: android, pdf, android-gradle-plugin

So I am trying to use [this library](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=3761) in my android app to be able to show pdf files. However, when I add the install line to my `build.gradle` file, Android Studio says that all Android support libraries should use the same version. This happens because the library uses `com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0` while my project is using `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0`.

I want to know if there is a way to get around this and use the library in my project, or if I would have to fork and update the library myself to make it work.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

simply exclude it from the build:

```
api ("com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2") {
    exclude group: "com.android.support", module: "appcompat-v7"
}
```